# PHP script only works when I refresh page how can I resolve it

Tags: php

In PHP quiz script it only works when page refresh once.

it happens on first question after this from second question php script works fine how can I solve this issue.

I added php script that auto refresh page one time but it refreshing on every question but it's not required I have issue only with first question.

**Quiz.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("database.php");
extract($_POST);
extract($_GET);
extract($_SESSION);
/*$rs=mysqli_query($cn,"select * from mst_question where test_id=$tid",) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
if($_SESSION[qn]>mysqli_num_rows($rs))
{
    unset($_SESSION[qn]);
    exit;
}*/

if(isset($subid) && isset($testid)){
    $_SESSION[sid]=$subid;
    $_SESSION[tid]=$testid;
    header("location:quiz.php");
}

if(!isset($_SESSION[sid]) || !isset($_SESSION[tid])){
    header("location: index.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Online Quiz</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="quiz.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<?php
include("header.php");

$query="select * from mst_question";

$rs=mysqli_query($cn,"select * from mst_question where test_id=$tid") or die(mysqli_connect_error());
if(!isset($_SESSION[qn])){
    $_SESSION[qn]=0;
    mysqli_query($cn,"delete from mst_useranswer where sess_id='" . session_id() ."'") or die(mysqli_connect_error());
    $_SESSION[trueans]=0;
}else{
    if($submit=='Next Question' && isset($ans)){
        mysqli_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs);   
        mysqli_query($cn,"insert into mst_useranswer(sess_id, test_id, que_des, ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,true_ans,your_ans) values ('".session_id()."', $tid,'$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]', '$row[6]','$row[7]','$ans')") or die(mysqli_connect_error());
        if($ans==$row[7]){
            $_SESSION[trueans]=$_SESSION[trueans]+1;
        }
        $_SESSION[qn]=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
    }else if($submit=='Get Result' && isset($ans)){
        mysqli_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs);   
        mysqli_query($cn,"insert into mst_useranswer(sess_id, test_id, que_des, ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4,true_ans,your_ans) values ('".session_id()."', $tid,'$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]', '$row[6]','$row[7]','$ans')") or die(mysqli_connect_error());
        if($ans==$row[7]){
            $_SESSION[trueans]=$_SESSION[trueans]+1;
        }
        echo "<h1 class=head1> Result</h1>";
        $_SESSION[qn]=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
        echo "<Table align=center><tr class=tot><td>Total Question<td> $_SESSION[qn]";
        echo "<tr class=tans><td>True Answer<td>".$_SESSION[trueans];
        $w = $_SESSION[qn]-$_SESSION[trueans];
        echo "<tr class=fans><td>Wrong Answer<td> ". $w;
        echo "</table>";
        mysqli_query($cn,"insert into mst_result(login,test_id,test_date,score) values('$login','$tid',NULL,'$_SESSION[trueans]')") or die(mysqli_connect_error());
        echo "<h1 align=center><a href=review.php> Review Question</a> </h1>";
        unset($_SESSION[qn]);
        unset($_SESSION[sid]);
        unset($_SESSION[tid]);
        unset($_SESSION[trueans]);
        exit;
    }
}

$rs = mysqli_query($cn,"select * from mst_question where test_id=$tid") or die(mysqli_connect_error());

if($_SESSION[qn]>mysqli_num_rows($rs)-1)
{
    unset($_SESSION[qn]);
    echo "<h1 class=head1>Some Error  Occured</h1>";
    session_destroy();
    echo "Please <a href=index.php> Start Again</a>";
    exit;
}

mysqli_data_seek($rs,$_SESSION[qn]);

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs);
echo "<form name=myfm method=post action=quiz.php>";
echo "<table width=100%> <tr> <td width=30>&nbsp;<td> <table border=0>";

$n = $_SESSION[qn]+1;
echo "<tR><td><span class=style2>Que ".  $n .": $row[2]</style>";
echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name=ans value=1>$row[3]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8> <input type=radio name=ans value=2>$row[4]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name=ans value=3>$row[5]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8><input type=radio name=ans value=4>$row[6]";

if($_SESSION[qn]<mysqli_num_rows($rs)-1){
    echo "<tr><td><input type=submit name=submit value='Next Question'></form>";
}else{
    echo "<tr><td><input type=submit name=submit value='Get Result'></form>";
    echo "</table></table>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This depends on what you actually mean by "it only works" on first refresh. It certainly is executed fpr _every_ request, also the first one. So what is _not_ "working" then?

Comment: @arkascha When any one redirect to this page they have to refresh page how can I stop so other can reach first question directly

Comment: Ah, so the issue is that on the first request it is not the first question that is asked.

Comment: There are soooo many issues with this code that I am tempted to assume that this is a test... To answer the question asked though I would comment that most likely `$tid` is not set during the first request, since no session yet exists, so `$_SESSION` is not yet filled...

Comment: @arkascha I will trying thanks for replying

Comment: @arkascha I unable to do how can I set $tid in first request

Comment: I cannot tell you, I have no idea what that is meant to be. However you rely on it being set right in the first query: `"select * from mst_question where test_id=$tid"`. That query certainly will fail if the variable is _not_ set. So you certainly do have some idea what that variable is meant to hold. _We_ cannot tell you since you did not explain your code but simply dumped it here asking "does not work, how can I fix it". We cannot magically guess what you are trying to implement, so we cannot answer that question. We can only point our some obvious issues with the code. Which I tried to do.

Comment: @arkascha okay thanks for guide that's

Comment: I formatted the code so that it is readable, please format your code the next time you post a question.

Comment: @Mehdi Thanks and I will do from next time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@arkascha and @Mehdi thanks for help. my problem solved. there is confusion in two word in query $tid and $testid I replaced both with $testid and my code working properly

Comment: Since it was a typo you probably could delete the whole thing. It would have been easier if you hadn't answered. Try to delete the answer first.